# What is the act of self-referencing?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, word-formation, variants

Ok, so something can be *self-referencing*.

"This sentence contains thirty-eight letters."

or

"This is not a pipe."

[image: The Treachery Of Images (1928-29) by René Magritte depicts a pipe along with text stating "This is not a pipe."]

But what is "doing that" called?

Along the lines of how *self-deprecating* is *self-deprecation*.

Thought maybe… *self-referenciation*, but that doesn't seem to exist. How ironic.

Comment: I actually don't think this is self- *de* referencing- This is just a self-reference, and *doing that* is called '*making a self-reference*', and things that do it are described as '*self-referential*'

Comment: @jwpat7 I edited the question, as you're right.. The actual question I was asking changed between writing the "subject" and the "body" resulting in a bit of a befuddled mess.  So Jim. the idea, i guess then, would be the noun form of actively being self-referential.

Comment: @alexgray I guess I'd call that *self-referral*

Comment: noun: *self-reference*; verb: *self-reference*; adjective: *self-referential*; adverb: *self-referentially*.

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is ***self-reference***.

"*This is a sentence.*"
Ah, I like it when an example makes a self-reference.

[EDIT]

---

Usage as ***verb***:

> ARTIST OF THE DAY: *[Emmy the Great Charts the Stages of 'Second Love'](https://myspace.com/article/2016/5/10/emmy-the-great-second-love-artist-of-the-day)* By Nilina Mason-Campbell
>   myspace.com (registration) (blog)-May 10, 2016
>   *I also have this jokey thing in my head about albums that **self-reference**. There's something goofy and overblown about it (like my band name).*

Comment: This is a comment.  (I enjoy self-references as well.)

Comment: This is not a comment, it's a paradox, but it is self-referential nonetheless.

Comment: @JR: Good one, that!

Answer (score 2):

The OED's definition of *self-reference* includes a mention of propositions and paradoxes, making it especially apt for your two examples:

> Reference to oneself or itself; the direction of one's attention at
>   oneself, esp. in forming a comparative assessment of one's
>   characteristics or experience; spec. in Philos., the characteristic or
>   quality of referring to itself contained in certain paradoxes,
>   propositions, or statements.

To answer your question, then, I guess the act of self-reference is called a *self-reference*.

My favorite self-referencing paradox goes something like this:

[image]